# Wired GPS Head Units or GPS Head Units with An Airplane Mode Feature

Tags: bike-computer

I'm looking for a Jump starter power bank for GPS head unit that is wired (doesn't have wireless capabilities) or has an airplane mode feature. In the wireless world we live in, I think going on a bike ride is a great opportunity to get away from wireless signals. I still want to track my ride and use Strava / TrainingPeaks, in fact the more bells and whistles on the head unit, the better, just not the wireless.

I have a Garmin Edge 20 for this reason, but the battery life is starting to wane. I bought a Hammerhead Karoo 2 because it has an airplane mode feature, but it doesn't turn off the wireless when tracking a ride. When I started it up for the first time, it had all the features I wanted - I could turn all the wireless features (wifi, Bluetooth & ANT+, phone Bluetooth) individually off and turn the head unit on airplane mode, and it stayed on airplane mode when tracking a ride as well. Unfortunately, the most recent software update removed the ability to turn off some of these wireless features, and despite there still being an airplane mode feature, it still emits a signal during a ride when on airplane mode (I checked with a meter).

I know I could use my phone for this, but I'd rather have a head unit on my handlebars. Thanks for your help!

PS Wireless head units still emit a signal when not paired with another device (power meter, HR monitor, phone, etc.). It's some sort of search function for the pairing. I've checked this with a meter on the Wahoo Element Bolt and now Hammerhead Karoo 2.

Comment: To paraphrase, you want a USB power bank that allows the head unit to work and charge at the same time, while not communicating with a phone or the internet in any way but can still talk to sensors ?

Comment: Do modern bike computers really not allow you to turn off Bluetooth advertising and Wifi? In any case, the transmit powers are tiny, in a harmless frequency range and happen in short bursts. I’d be more concerned about a minor impact on battery life.